# Box2D:Angular Impulse and torque

Tags: box2d

How to handle a scenario when a sudden impact causes angular impulse and then constant torque too, like a weight dropping on a wooden plank which can rotate about a revolute joint?Weight impact would cause angular impulse and then constant torque too.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to implement?

Comment: What do you mean by "handle"? Box2D is supposed to be doing all this for you already.